# Interface Builder cuts off text input for long strings when using attributed text

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, uilabel, nsattributedstring

Is this a bug or by design? The text input is cut off when text is getting long. Using Xcode 8. How can I avoid this? It stops me from inputting the text I want.

[image]

I realized that you can make the thing stop cutting off text by simply making the Xcode window and/or panel wider. I still think though that this kind of control usually should allow for scrolling within itself... I seem to remember that it did at times, but I just can't get it working now.